# GRUB doesn't show all kernels

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, linux-kernel

I installed 16.04 over 14.04.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

The problem is that old kernel loaded

```
uname -a
Linux bendyna-ub 4.2.0-38-generic #45~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 9 09:27:51 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But kernel 4.4.0 also installed. And it is in /boot/grub/grub.cfg

```
 menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-97-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-97-generic-advanced-e8bffb7c-4340-4424-be72-119b53843aa4' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  e8bffb7c-4340-4424-be72-119b53843aa4
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e8bffb7c-4340-4424-be72-119b53843aa4
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-97-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-97-generic root=UUID=e8bffb7c-4340-4424-be72-119b53843aa4 ro  
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-97-generic
}
```

And I can't see it in GRUB menu after restart. grub.cfg has 7 items in menu

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-97-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-97-generic-advanced-e8bffb7c-4340-4424-be72-119b53843aa4' {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-97-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-97-generic-init-upstart-e8bffb7c-4340-4424-be72-119b53843aa4' {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-97-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-97-generic-recovery-e8bffb7c-4340-4424-be72-119b53843aa4' {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-38-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-38-generic-advanced-e8bffb7c-4340-4424-be72-119b53843aa4' {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-38-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-38-generic-init-upstart-e8bffb7c-4340-4424-be72-119b53843aa4' {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-38-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-38-generic-recovery-e8bffb7c-4340-4424-be72-119b53843aa4' {
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
```

In GRUB menu I see only Ubuntu and "Advanced options". In "Advanced options" submenu there are only 2 items 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-38-generic' and 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-38-generic (recovery mode)'

Also it's strange that GRUB version in menu is 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2. And grub-install --version is grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.12

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If an answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ to the left of the text, which means "yes, this is THE answer"!

Answer (score 0):

I managed problem - it is required to reinstall grub in EFI

This helped me https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#UEFI_systems